# Removing a file before upload, using Filereader interface

Tags: jquery, html, image, upload, filereader

I'm using File API's Filereader to create thumbnails of various images before upload. In addition to each thumbnail, a "delete" button is created, so the user can remove the non wanted images before the upload. Thing is, if the delete button is clicked, the object is removed from the DOM, but when hitting upload, all selected images are uploaded, even those previously removed.

I'm trying to figure out a way to remove these deleted files before the upload, but I can't seem to find where they are getting stored.

Here's the script that I'm using:

```
$(window).load(function(){

var j = 0;

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {

                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.className = 'imageMask '+ j +'';
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb '+ j +'" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" /> <span class="deleteBtn" onClick="removeFunc(\'' + j + '\')">x</span>'].join('');
                j += 1;                  

                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);



});
```

And here is the remove function I'm using:

```
function removeFunc(e){
    $('.imageMask.' + e).remove();
}
```

Thanks for your help!